SYSTEM reports file Name without extension
I'm using PowerShell to deploy fonts. To get the name of the font for the registry key, I'm using a Shell.Application object to get the file metadata.
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 

$fontFolders = "Folder1","Folder2"
$fontReg = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"

foreach ($fontFolder in $fontFolders){
    $fontList = Get-ChildItem -Path "$fontFolder\*" -Include ('*.otf','*.ttf')
    $fontFolderFullPath = (Resolve-Path "$fontFolder").path
    $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($fontFolderFullPath) 

    foreach ($font in $objFolder.items() | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.otf' -or $_.Name -like '*.ttf'}){
        #21 is ostensibly the attribute code for Title (since Vista). Possible for it to change with OS releases
        #https://web.archive.org/web/20131021234438/http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880
        #https://forums.powershell.org/t/how-to-find-metadata-is-available-from-file-properties/23751
        $title = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($font, 21)
        if (-Not ((Get-Item "$fontReg").property -contains "$title (TrueType)")) {
            Copy-Item $font.Path "C:\Windows\Fonts"
            New-ItemProperty -Name "$title (TrueType)" -Path "$fontReg" -PropertyType string -Value $font.Name
        }
    }
}

This script works fine when run under the local user, but it fails when run as SYSTEM because of how I'm filtering for font files: | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.otf' -or $_.Name -like '*.ttf'.
Running the following script:
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace("C:\Path\to\my\Fonts")
foreach ($font in $objFolder.items()){Write-Output $font}

I see this from the local user:
Application  : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Name         : FontName-UltraItalic.otf
Path         : C:\Path\Font1.otf
GetLink      :
GetFolder    :
IsLink       : False
IsFolder     : False
IsFileSystem : True
IsBrowsable  : False
ModifyDate   : 7/30/2024 10:55:24 PM
Size         : 45616
Type         : OpenType font file

and this from SYSTEM:
Application  : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Name         : FontName-UltraItalic
Path         : C:\Path\Font1.otf
GetLink      :
GetFolder    :
IsLink       : False
IsFolder     : False
IsFileSystem : True
IsBrowsable  : False
ModifyDate   : 7/30/2024 10:55:24 PM
Size         : 45616
Type         : OpenType font file

Notably, under SYSTEM, Name does not include .otf. I changed my filter from $_.Name to $_.Path, and I modified the registry value creation to be "$(Split-Path -Path $font.Path -Leaf -Resolve)" instead of $font.Name, so everything works fine now.
But why does SYSTEM not see file extensions? Is there something I can toggle to make it see extensions?

This is because the output of 'Shell.Application' depends on whether Explorer is set to show filename extensions or not.
The setting to show filename extensions is save in the registry key 'Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced', but it looks that the system user don't have the key 'Advanced', you can try this (untested):
# Define SID for SYSTEM user
$SID = "S-1-5-18"

$BaseRegPath = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$SID\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"

if (-not (Test-Path "$BaseRegPath\Advanced")) {
    New-Item -Path $BaseRegPath -Name "Advanced"
}

Set-ItemProperty -Path "$BaseRegPath\Advanced" -Name "HideFileExt" -Value 0


Confirming that setting the registry key successfully forces file extensions to show under SYSTEM. Thank you
